# Heroku Postgres extension errors with `rake db:structure:load` or `rake db:setup`?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When running `rake db:structure:load` on Heroku, we get the following error:

```
$ heroku run rake db:structure:load -a my_heroku_app
Running rake db:structure:load on ⬢ my_heroku_app... up, run.9343 (Standard-1X)
psql:/app/db/structure.sql:21: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -q -f /app/db/structure.sql d7u1inlf2d16bd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku's [current suggestion](https://help.heroku.com/AHH2KNSR/why-do-i-get-postgres-extension-errors-when-i-run-rake-db-structure-load-or-rake-db-setup) is to manually comment out all `COMMENT ON EXTENSION` lines in structure.sql or switch to schema.rb. Another approach is to add a small prepend that fixes this automatically.  I have it in our config/initializers folder, but many other places should work:

https://gist.github.com/jsilvestri/0210d83b7ee2aa54876e2be3323dd3fc